# 'ajaxFunction is not defined' when sending AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update another page, `userreg.php`, from `index.php`. Here is my code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title> User List </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datacss.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#img1").click(function(){    
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userreg.php',    
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('html').html(html);
                }
            });
       });
   });
   </script>
   </head>
  <body>
<div id= "ajax">
  <img id="img1" src="images/bg/adduser.png"  onclick="ajaxFunction()">
 <div class="search">
 <form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="doSearch" value="1">
  <input type="submit" id ="img2" name="submit" value="" /></br>
   <a href="index.php"><img src="images/bg/reset.png" alt="RESET" /></a>
   </form>
 </div>

          <table id="mytable" class="tablesorter">
                    <tbody>

            <tr>
                                <th id="name" >Name</th>
                                <th id="email">Email</th>


                                <th id="dob">DOB</th>

                                <th id="image">Image</th>

                                <th>EDIT </th>

                                <th>DELETE</th>


                            </tr>




<?php
if(isset($_GET['doSearch'])) {
if($_GET['doSearch']==1) {

       include'con_search.php';

  }

}

else{
    include('getuserdata.php');



}
?>


                               </tbody>

                        </table>



 </div>



 <div id="pagination">
        <div id="pagiCount">
            <?php
                if(isset($pages))
                {
                    if($pages > 1)
                    {    if($cur_page > $num_links)     // for taking to page 1 //
                        {   $dir = "first";
                            echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.(1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                        }
                       if($cur_page > 1)
                        {
                            $dir = "prev";
                            echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($cur_page-1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                        }

                        for($x=$start ; $x<=$end ;$x++)
                        {

                            echo ($x == $cur_page) ? '<strong>'.$x.'</strong> ':'<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                        }
                        if($cur_page < $pages )
                        {   $dir = "next";
                            echo '<span id="next"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($cur_page+1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                        }
                        if($cur_page < ($pages-$num_links) )
                        {   $dir = "last";

                            echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$pages.'">'.$dir.'</a> ';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I get an error in Firebug:

> ReferenceError: ajaxFunction is not defined

Comment: have you included the `jquery` library ?

Comment: yes i included <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: The error appears unrelated to the code you've shown.

Comment: I edited my code so please suggest me

Comment: you havent defined your method `ajaxFunction()` in your script, which you have given for click event callback for image with id `img1`

Comment: I want to use that for table shorting

Comment: But why two click events,besides you can do the same on jquery click handler

Comment: after doing this it's all fine!!     <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#img1").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userreg.php',

                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {




                  $("#style1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                     $('body').html(html);
                }
            });


   });
    });
    </script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
<img id="img1" src="images/bg/adduser.png"  onclick="ajaxFunction()">
```

You have specified that the `ajaxFunction` function should be called when the image is clicked, but that function does not exist. As you have used jQuery to bind a function on `$("#img1").click`, you can simply remove that attribute like this:

```
<img id="img1" src="images/bg/adduser.png">
```

Comment: i dont get full css from loading file

Comment: That doesn't seem I be related to the question you asked?

Answer (score 0):

you havent defined your method `ajaxFunction()` in your script, which you have given for click event callback(inline handler) for image with id `img1`.

**Mistakes in your code:**

- you have defined two callback handlers for click, one `inline` and other inside `document.ready()` in jQuery syntax .
- Since the inline click handler takes precendence, JS Engine is trying to find `ajaxFunction()`, which is not available.

to correct your error, just remove the `inline` click handler from the image tag with id `img1`